# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects Can someone please help a newbie with their code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Any help is appreciated, also any big flaws or something you see in the way im formatting or something basic, please point it out. Thanks!

```
day = raw_input("How many days?")
locations = raw_input("Where to?")
days = str(day)
location = str(locations)
spendingMoney = 100


def hotel(days):
    return 140 * days

def destination(location):
    if location == "los angeles":
        return 300
    if location == "boston":
        return 400

def rental(days):
    if days < 2:
        return 40 * days
    if days >= 2 and days <= 6:
        return days * 30
     if days >= 7:
        return days * 25

def total_cost(days, location):
    return hotel(days) + destination(location) + rental(days)


print total_cost(days, location)
```

Comment: @Volatility Thank you so much! I can't believe that's all I needed to change, and I had even gotten this idea earlier, but also tried changing location to an integer, which wouldn't work. Just wondering, are there any bad formattings or ways that the code could be improved to be shorter or something? If not, thanks again, you saved me from some more frusturation =D

Comment: Well really the only thing that could be changed is `days >= 2 and days <= 6` to `2 <= days <= 6`. (Also the third `if` in `rental` is off by a space, but that's probably just a typo)

Answer (score 2):

First thing to understand is that `raw_input` returns a string, so there's no need to cast the result to a string afterwards.

What you want (I think) is to cast `day` to an `int`, so you need to change the top part.

```
day = raw_input("How many days?")
location = raw_input("Where to?")
days = int(day)
spendingMoney = 100
```

In your original code, `days` was a string, and so you were trying to add a string to and integer (which raised the error).

Multiplying a string by an integer is perfectly valid, as it simply repeats the original string several times over.

```
print 'foobar' * 5
# foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `days` is a string.

when you do

```
return 140 * days
```

it actually multiples your string to 140.
so if `days` == "5" you will have "555555555555555555..." (140 characters)

you want to operate with integers so do
`days = int(day)` instead